# android.view.WindowLeaked when dealing with Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, optionmenu

I want to call a Dialog by pressing a button on optionMenu but I face the following error:

> android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity *android.MessageActivity has
>   leaked window
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{b1da86e8
>   V.E..... R.....I. 0,0-640,418} that was originally added here

my code is :

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_item_contact:
        myDialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.contactus);
        myDialog.setCancelable(true);
        etSubject = (EditText) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.etSubject);
        etText = (EditText) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.etText);
        bSend = (Button) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.bSend);
        myDialog.setTitle("contact us");
        myDialog.show();
```

The thing is when I put this code in onCreateView there is no problem and the Dialog shows without any errors

Comment: when the error occurs? Before start on after?

Comment: this error usually happens when you call `show` the your activity was finished

Comment: the activity is not finished, when I press the button the Dialog shows for a second then terminated.

Comment: when I put this code in onCreateview the dialog shows on start without any problem